# Elasticsearch ngram with min_ngram 3 filters out 2 letter word?

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram

If you use `min_gram=3` in index time,
words that consist of 2 letters wont' be indexed

If you use `min_gram=3` in search time,
words that consist of 2 letters won't be used in search

Is there a way to preserve the 2 letters words at index/search time?

Comment: Well, by definition, yes. How about using min_gram=2?